# Rails 5 - Query redundantly searching on associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using datatables to display 4 columns.

Name | Count | Nearest Due Date | Furthest Due Date.

I finally have the tables displaying (I believe) the correct data based on testing, however it is now taking an *excessively*long time to query and I believe it's just due to my hack-n-slash method of making it work. The queries look clean/proper from a transactional point, but there is a lot. I believe I should instead be leveraging `.join` and `.pluck` but I'm not sure the proper way.

Attached is my function that creates the data. (On init I send a `clients_resource` that is a list of -all- of the users active clients. I have added inline comments for brevity.)

```
  def data
    clients.map do |client|
      [
        ## The output is a link to the client, raw industry field, the number of 'tasks' they currently have
        ## as noted in ##TASK_COUNT##
        ## Then I want to link to the nearest TASK due date. (task_end_date)
        ## This happened in ##TASK_END_DATE##
        ## The final one is similar but finds the end_date withinj the Project
        ##   This is in ##PROJECT_END_DATE##
        link_to(client.name, client),
        client.industry,
        client.status,

        ##TASK_COUNT##
        if client.tasks.present? ## My purpose here is to avoid 500 errors if a client has no tasks. Seemed like a hack
            task = client.tasks.order(:task_start_date).first
            project = Project.find(task.project_id)
            link_to(client.tasks.count, url_helpers.project_tasks_path(project))
        else
            client.tasks.count
        end,
        ##TASK_END_DATE##
        if client.tasks.present?  ## Again, hack method
          task =  client.tasks.order('task_end_date desc').first ## Exactly as it says - Was only way I could get the ''
                                                          ## Typing this out I realize this logic is incorrect. It should return the NEAREST future task_end_date, but it is returning the furthest task_end_date, perior
          project = task.project ## Was a hack to try to reduce the queries since the relationship will allow this query to work
          #project = client.projects.order('end_date desc').first
          if task.task_end_date.future? ## Hack to ensure the task_end_date is in the future other-wise it should print a warning
            link_to(task.task_end_date.strftime("%B %e, %Y"), url_helpers.project_task_path(project, task))

          else
              link_to("Is this project late?", url_helpers.project_tasks_path(client.nearest_project_id))
          end
        else
          'No Projects'
        end,
          ##PROJECT_END_DATE##
        if client.tasks.present? && client.nearest_project_start.present? ##Hack to ensure it has tasks, and that the nearest_project_start has content.
            project = Project.find(client.furthest_project_id) ## Gets the ProjectID for the furthest_project_id - This is handled by the model on save to help alliviate queries
            link_to(project.end_date.strftime("%B %e, %Y"), url_helpers.project_task_path(project, client.furthest_project_id))
        else
            'No Tasks Pending'
        end
      ]
    end
  end
```

Again, this feels *unbelievably* wrong, but I am unsure how to better put it.

I'm also attaching a snippet of the 3 models ERD in case it helps.

The flow is

Client -> Projects -> Tasks, but travels back up also. (So Task.first.client will return the client).

I'm trying to figure out how to make these queries more clean and also more accurate. Is just doing raw SQL my go-to? I'm much better with SQL than I am joining methods.

**A snippet of the console during the query**

```
  User Load (1.8ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (1.8ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "clients" WHERE "clients"."user_id" = $1 AND (status != 'Not Active') AND (status != 'Suspended')  [["user_id", 1]]
  CACHE  (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "clients" WHERE "clients"."user_id" = $1 AND (status != 'Not Active') AND (status != 'Suspended')  [["user_id", 1]]
  Client Load (2.1ms)  SELECT  "clients".* FROM "clients" WHERE "clients"."user_id" = $1 AND (status != 'Not Active') AND (status != 'Suspended') ORDER BY name asc LIMIT $2 OFFSET $3  [["user_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 30], ["OFFSET", 0]]
  Project Load (5.8ms)  SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."client_id" IN (2, 1, 4, 3)
  Task Load (2.1ms)  SELECT "tasks".* FROM "tasks" WHERE "tasks"."project_id" IN (5, 6, 3, 4, 1, 7, 2)
  Task Load (1.9ms)  SELECT  "tasks".* FROM "tasks" INNER JOIN "projects" ON "tasks"."project_id" = "projects"."id" WHERE "projects"."client_id" = $1 ORDER BY "tasks"."task_start_date" ASC LIMIT $2  [["client_id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Project Load (1.4ms)  SELECT  "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (1.8ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "tasks" INNER JOIN "projects" ON "tasks"."project_id" = "projects"."id" WHERE "projects"."client_id" = $1  [["client_id", 2]]
  Task Load (4.1ms)  SELECT  "tasks".* FROM "tasks" INNER JOIN "projects" ON "tasks"."project_id" = "projects"."id" WHERE "projects"."client_id" = $1 ORDER BY task_end_date asc LIMIT $2  [["client_id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE Project Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE Project Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Task Load (2.0ms)  SELECT  "tasks".* FROM "tasks" INNER JOIN "projects" ON "tasks"."project_id" = "projects"."id" WHERE "projects"."client_id" = $1 ORDER BY "tasks"."task_start_date" ASC LIMIT $2  [["client_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Project Load (1.5ms)  SELECT  "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (1.8ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "tasks" INNER JOIN "projects" ON "tasks"."project_id" = "projects"."id" WHERE "projects"."client_id" = $1  [["client_id", 1]]
  Task Load (3.2ms)  SELECT  "tasks".* FROM "tasks" INNER JOIN "projects" ON "tasks"."project_id" = "projects"."id" WHERE "projects"."client_id" = $1 ORDER BY task_end_date asc LIMIT $2  [["client_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE Project Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE Project Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (2.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "tasks" INNER JOIN "projects" ON "tasks"."project_id" = "projects"."id" WHERE "projects"."client_id" = $1  [["client_id", 4]]
Started GET "/clients" for 73.106.189.182 at 2017-10-15 01:18:19 +0000
  Task Load (29.1ms)  SELECT  "tasks".* FROM "tasks" INNER JOIN "projects" ON "tasks"."project_id" = "projects"."id" WHERE "projects"."client_id" = $1 ORDER BY "tasks"."task_start_date" ASC LIMIT $2  [["client_id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Cannot render console from 73.106.189.182! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by ClientsController#index as HTML
  Project Load (45.9ms)  SELECT  "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (11.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "tasks" INNER JOIN "projects" ON "tasks"."project_id" = "projects"."id" WHERE "projects"."client_id" = $1  [["client_id", 3]]
  User Load (5.8ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Task Load (100.6ms)  SELECT  "tasks".* FROM "tasks" INNER JOIN "projects" ON "tasks"."project_id" = "projects"."id" WHERE "projects"."client_id" = $1 ORDER BY task_end_date asc LIMIT $2  [["client_id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendering clients/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  CACHE Project Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendered clients/index.html.erb within layouts/application (9.6ms)
  CACHE Project Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

Essentially these ~20 lines are my concern, the load time is also unbearable even on prod. Before I started refining the queries it wasn't this extensive.

Welcome any input - I'm unsure what other code base to attach.

Answer (score 0):

To speed things up and avoid those "n+1" queries, you can use eager loading (includes) and instead of counting all associated records every time use a counter cache. The following resources describe these techniques:

[Eager Loading Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations)

[ActiveRecord Associations Counter Cache (4.1.2.3)](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs-to-association-reference)